# Why did the server respond with a status of 415 - API Post Method

Tags: javascript, api, spring-restcontroller

I'm trying to create my own API using Spring Boot, which for now uses access to external data from an air quality API.

I have a CityInfo entity:

```
@Entity
public class CityInfo{
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;


    public CityInfo(){

    }

    public CityInfo(String id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
.
.
.
}
```

The Rest Controller:

```
    @Autowired
    private CityInfoService cityInfoService;
    @Autowired
    private CityInfoRepository cityInfoRepository;

    @GetMapping("/CityInfo")
    public List<CityInfo> getAllCityInfo() {
        return cityInfoRepository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping ("/CityInfo")
    public void addCityInfo(@RequestBody CityInfo cityInfo) {
        cityInfoService.add(cityInfo);
    }
```

When it comes to posting to "localhost:port/CityInfo", the postman works fine with 
{"id":"1","name":"London"} and it is read in "/CityInfo".

When I try to post using JS, it returns Error 415 which supposedly is "415 Unsupported Media Type".

```
function postData(){
    let id = "31";
    let name = "CITYCITY"
    fetch('http://localhost:8084/CityInfo', {
        method: 'POST',
        body:JSON.stringify({"id":id,
                            "name":name})
    }).then((res) => res.text())
        .then((text)=>console.log("text:"+ text))
        .catch((err)=>console.log("err:" + err))
}
postData();
```

On the console it is returned:
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 415 ()"

I suppose i'm sending JSON with the wrong format, but it doesn't appear to me at least.

Any help would be great.Ty

Edit:
Postman photo
[image]

```
function postData(){
    let id = "31";
    let name = "CITYCITY"
    fetch('http://localhost:8084/CityInfo', {
        method: 'POST',
        body:JSON.stringify({"id":id,
                            "name":name}),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        contentEncoding: 'gzip',
        contentEncoding: 'deflate',
        contentEncoding: 'br',
    }).then((res) => res.text())
        .then((text)=>console.log("text:"+ text))
        .catch((err)=>console.log("err:" + err))
}
postData()
```

It returns:
POST http://localhost:8084/CityInfo 415

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415) explains what a 415 response means.

It's likely your Content-Type or Content-Encoding is wrong in your postData function.

At any rate, you need to check what the endpoint is expecting and make sure your request conforms to those expectations.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have seen the documentation before regarding the error presented. From what I am understanding, my Controller takes the information that it is posted and create a CityInfo Object that will be added to the repository. I simply can not figure out why it works fine with Postman, using: {"id":"1","name":"London"} and if try to use the JS function, it won't work... It seems that I'm trying sending a JSON file with a wrong format, meanwhile i think it is sending: {"id":"31","name":"CITYCITY"} which should be accepted

Comment: Have you checked your Content-Type and Content-Encoding?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding

Comment: So I was looking on the Postman app.. i sent JSON file with Content-Type="application/json". Knowing that, i tried to include the content-type attribute in the JS that creates the JSON file (SInce I'm not sure, I'll add a image regaring my postman app and code for the adapted JS function)

Comment: It did not work and returned:POST http://localhost:8084/CityInfo 415

Comment: Read the docs for using Fetch. Content-Type needs to be a header.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 0):

So basically i was sending a JSON document with the wrong format.
When using the Postman, it has 'Content-Type': 'application/json'

Here is the edited JS:

```
function postData(){
    let id = "31";
    let name = "CITYCITY"
    fetch('http://localhost:8084/CityInfo', {
        method: 'POST',
        body:JSON.stringify({"id":id,
                            "name":name}),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then((res) => res.text())
        .then((text)=>console.log("text:"+ text))
        .catch((err)=>console.log("err:" + err))
}
postData()
```